# Is it okay to Query the DownloadManager on the UI Thread?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-download-manager

The DownloadManager has a method [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#query%28android.app.DownloadManager.Query%29). My question is if it's okay to call this method on the UI Thread, or if it should only be called from a background thread?

Can calling it ever cause an ANR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one looks at the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java#L960) of the `query()` method:

```
public Cursor query(Query query) {
  Cursor underlyingCursor = query.runQuery(mResolver, UNDERLYING_COLUMNS, mBaseUri);
  if (underlyingCursor == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return new CursorTranslator(underlyingCursor, mBaseUri);
}
```

... this could be break down to the question whether it is safe to access cursors in the UI thread. See Mark Murphy's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319729/1140682) to this. Extract:

> So query the DownloadManager in a background thread.